# Change color in table row depending on cell value (minus/plus) in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have done a table of history transactions. In my transaction db I have a column named QuantityChange. Where values can be negative or positive.

I would like to set the row color to red, if its a minus value and green if positive (or zero).

What is the best solution to this?

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Storage
        </th>
        <th>
            Product
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity change
        </th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr class="@item.QuantityChange">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock.Storage.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock.Product.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.QuantityChange > 0)
              {

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityChange, new { 
style = "color:#00ff00" })

                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityChange, new { 
style = "color:#ff0000" })

                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution for you.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr style="color:@(item.QuantityChange >= 0 ? "#00ff00" : "#ff0000")">
        <!-- insert other columns here -->
        <td> <!-- this has been modified -->
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityChange)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@{
    String color;
}
```

And in your table add the styling to each  element as required.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
    @{
        switch((item.QuantityChange)
        {
            case >0:
                color:"#00ff00";
                break;
            default:
                color:"color:#ff0000";
                break;
        }
    <td style="color:@color">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityChange)
    </td>
```